# Problems with unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: pic]

I first assigned float for the variable hh, but unity gave me an error that it could not convert double to float as vectors used floats. Which was really weird considering I already named it a float. So then I tried assigning hh as a double and then changing it back to float in the vector3 args. Surprisingly it worked which makes no sense at all since its technically the same thing.

Comment: *Problems with unity* is a meaningless question title, and we can't help you with problems with code we cannot see. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post and formatted so that it's readable. Please [edit] to update your question title, clearly explain the problem you're having, include the relevant code directly into your post, and ask a specific question related to that code so that we can try to help. You'll find your experiences here are much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] to learn how the site works before posting.

Answer (score 1):

make it

```c#
private float hh = -6.74f;
```

mind the `f` it tells c# that this is a `float` value. See [Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types). Without that the `-6.74` is a `double` which can not be assigned implicitly to a `float` field/variable but would require an explicit cast `(float)`.

It can not be implicitly converted since `double` has a higher precision than `float`. The other way round it can be done implicitly since you wouldn't lose any information.

So since Unity anyway provides all information as `float` it makes no sense to use `double` for comparing and calculating with transform information.

---

Later for the vector you used

```c#
(float)hh
```

which is definitely **not** `technically the same thing`. This is an explicit typecast which you *could* have also done when assigning the value

```c#
private float hh = (float)-6.74;
```

And before you are doing

```c#
transform.position.x < -6.74
```

this works because here the `-6.74` is not converted into a `float` but the other way round: `transform.position.x` which is a `float` **can** be implicitly converted into a more precise `double`. Therefore what implicitely happens is actually

```c#
(double)transform.position.x < -6.74
```

using the `double` comparison operator `<`!

These

```c#
(float)transform.position.y
```

are completely redundant since `transform.position.y` already **is** a `float`.

---

Finally: You know that you can write your code shorter by simply using

```c#
var getaxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
var position = transform.position;
position.x = Mathf.Max(-6.74f, position.x + getaxis * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed);
transform.position = position;
```